# How to display a dynamically generated svg-image in JSP (using Spring MVC)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

In my Spring MVC application, an svg-image is to be generated by controller "on-fly" and displayed in JSP page. Is there an elegant method to do this using Spring MVC capabilities without saving the svg-image as a file?

Comment: Are you asking for someone to recommend a library?

Comment: I know how to generate svg. I need a method to transfer the svg to JSP. Can it be done just by adding of an attribute to the ModelAndView? What tags are to be used in the JSP for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me I would have an `img` tag on my JSP page with a `src` that points to a `@Controller` that invokes the svg generator and returns the generated svg as a Spring Resource or as a ByteArrayInputStream (although the latter may risk OOMs).

Comment: Can you give an example?